# Why is deleting a node from the center of a heap not n + log(n) time complexity?

Tags: time-complexity, runtime, heap

Suppose you have a binary heap and must delete node y from somewhere in its center. I.e. the node you must delete is not the first or last element.

My understanding is that you must first locate y in the heap before you can perform the delete on it.  I understand that locating y in the heap is O(n) because this requires a Search.  Then I understand that a delete operation may involve overwriting Y with a copy of the last element of the heap, and this copy must be sifted up or down until the heap property is satisfied, and this sifting is log(n).

So in summary, when you want to delete a center node from a heap, isn't the time complexity O(n) + log(n) because you must search for the item for O(n), then restore the heap property for log(n)?

Comment: The title and the body ask different questions. O(n) + O(logn) = O(n) anyway.

Comment: The idea is that you avoid to have to *search* the item, and have a map that gives the location of each item in the heap.

Comment: @trincot thanks for your feedback- ok so if I understand you correctly, there is an implicit assumption (that remains unsaid) that some data structure like a hashmap, with pointers to all nodes, is available with the heap?

Comment: There is no assumption. I just want to say that you could decide to use a hashmap next to the heap and maintain it with each operation on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Because finding an item in the heap and deleting an item in the heap are two separate operations.

The fact remains that if you know where the items is in the heap, removing that item from the heap is, in the worst case, an O(log n) operation.

There are multiple ways of finding out where an item is in the heap. One is a sequential scan of the heap to find the item. Another was pointed out in comments: a hashmap that gives the location. I can envision plenty of other situations where the object's position in the heap is known, and all you have to do is delete it.